# SQL for booking a holiday - Using a Sub query to evaluate a second table

Tags: sql

Hi I have a list of properties and a list of bookings. When I do a search I need to find the availability for a property.
 
I think I need a sub query. I have been looking into the ANY syntax.

Here what a sample data may look like.

**Table of properties**

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Toms Cottage |
| 2 | Shambala |

**Table of Bookings**

| property_id | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-07-22 | 2022-07-23 |
| 2 | 2022-08-01 | 2022-08-31 |

Query to see if a property is available per booking record.

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    aa_bookings 
WHERE
    aa_bookings.start > '2022-12-31'
    OR
    aa_bookings.end < '2022-12-01'
```

A fuller example (and verified answer to the question):

```sql
SELECT
    aa_listings.id
FROM
    (
        aa_listings
        LEFT JOIN aa_features ON aa_listings.id = aa_features.listing_id
    )
WHERE
    aa_listings.id != ''
    AND
    aa_listings.deleted != 1
    AND
    hidden != 1
    AND
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            aa_bookings
        WHERE
            aa_bookings.start > '2022-07-31'
            AND
            aa_bookings.end < '2022-12-01'
            AND
            aa_bookings.listing_id = aa_listings.id
    )
    AND
    aa_features.Central Heating = 1;
```

I think I need to run this sub query for the `property_id`, so kind of needs a `JOIN` or something too?

Advice please :-)

Comment: Can you provide sample output that you require? What's the actual problem?

Comment: Don't you want `AND`, not `OR` in that `WHERE` clause? Otherwise you'll effectively dump the entire table...

Comment: I need to know if the property is available. I would like the id of the property returned form the first table if there is no clash in the booking table.

Comment: I may have over simplified the problem. There's another table of features. So when the features match and it's available then the property id is returned.

Comment: Something like this? SELECT aa_listings.id FROM (aa_listings LEFT JOIN aa_features ON aa_listings.id = aa_features.listing_id) WHERE aa_listings.id!='' AND aa_listings.deleted!=1 AND hidden!=1 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM aa_bookings WHERE aa_bookings.start > '2022-07-31' AND aa_bookings.end < '2022-12-01' AND aa_bookings.listing_id = aa_listings.id) AND aa_features.`Central Heating`=1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  id
FROM properties p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT
    1
  FROM bookings b
  WHERE b.start > '2022-12-31'
  AND b.[end] < '2022-12-01'
  AND b.property_id = p.id)
```

you could do something like this